# Removing duplicate objects from an array based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript

I have an array arr from which I want to remove duplicate objects which have
_ same `e_display_id`
_ and `e_type` as `P`.
In this case I want to only consider the object with `status==='N'`.

Below is input array arr:

```js
let arr = 
  [ { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33780, e_display_id: "EA-15-001", status: "Y" } 
  , { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33744, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "N" } 
  , { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" } 
  , { e_type: "P", e_record_id:   420, e_display_id: "PE-14-911", status: "Y" } 
  , { e_type: "P", e_record_id:   421, e_display_id: "PE-14-911", status: "N" } 
  , { e_type: "R", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" } 
  , { e_type: "R", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" } 
  ];
```

My current implementation:

I am using loadash methods to filter out `e_type` as `P`
and then checking if there is any duplicate `e_display_id`,
if there is then only consider the one which has `status` as `N`.

```js
let   clonedPursuits  = [...arr];
let   myarr           = _.filter(clonedPursuits, x => x.e_type === 'P');
const counts          = _.countBy(myarr, 'e_display_id');
  clonedPursuits      = _.filter(myarr, x => counts[x.e_display_id] > 1);
const uniqueAddresses = Array.from(new Set(clonedPursuits.map(a => a.e_display_id)))
                          .map(id => {
                 return clonedPursuits.find(a => a.e_display_id === id && a.status === "N");
                           });
console.log( uniqueAddresses );
```

Expected Output:

```js
[ { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33780, e_display_id: "EA-15-001", status: "Y" } 
, { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33744, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "N" } 
, { e_type: "P", e_record_id:   421, e_display_id: "PE-14-911", status: "N" } 
, { e_type: "R", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" } 
, { e_type: "R", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" } 
];
```

Current output:

```js
[ { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33744, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "N"} 
, { e_type: "P", e_record_id:   421, e_display_id: "PE-14-911", status: "N"} 
]
```

Comment: I don't understand the expected output, didn't you write that e_type as 'P' should be remove ?

Comment: To clarify, your conditions are: include the item if not `e_type: "P"`, else if `e_type: "P"` then filter out any duplicate "e_record_id" unless `status: "N"`?

Comment: can there be more than one duplicate of the items to be removed?

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes. there could be.

Comment: Not sure you're going to get much help unless you clarify what exactly your conditions are

Comment: status value is only `Y` or `N` and nothing else ?

Comment: if item is not e_type: "P", then include it irrespective of anything. Else if e_type: "P" then check if there are any duplicate "e_record_id". If there are duplicate e_record_id then check status and only include the one which has status: 'N'.

Comment: https://github.com/mihaifm/linq It works like (maybe)

Comment: @MisterJojo only 'Y' or 'N'.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that:

```js
const arr = 
  [ { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33780, e_display_id: "EA-15-001", status: "Y" } 
  , { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33744, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "N" } 
  , { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" }
  , { e_type: "P", e_record_id:   420, e_display_id: "PE-14-911", status: "Y" }
  , { e_type: "P", e_record_id:   421, e_display_id: "PE-14-911", status: "N" } 
  , { e_type: "R", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" } 
  , { e_type: "R", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" } 
  ] 

const res = arr.reduce((a,c,i,t)=>
  {
  if (c.e_type!=='P')
    a.push({...c})
  else
    {
    if (c.status==='N')
      a.push({...c})
    else if (!t.some(x=> x.e_type==='P' && x.e_display_id===c.e_display_id  && x.status==='N' ))
      a.push({...c})
    }
  return a
  },[])

console.log( res )

console.log( ' --------- original array direct removing:-----------------')
// If you prefer to delete the elements directly without creating another array:

for(let i=arr.length;i--;)
  {
  let c = arr[i]
  if (c.e_type!=='P') continue
  if (c.status==='N') continue
  if (!arr.some(x=> x.e_type==='P' && x.e_display_id===c.e_display_id  && x.status==='N' )) continue
  arr.splice(i,1)
  }
console.log(  arr )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You can do this with O(n) complexity, both of these solutions are O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it for you. The advantage to this solution is that it only makes (at most) two passes through the array of items, meaning it has an `O(n)` time complexity, so it is very efficient. The disadvantage to this solution is that it does not preserve the order of the items, so if order is important, they will need to be re-sorted, which makes the solution `O(nlog(n))`.

The idea behind this solution is to include the items that you know will be added on the first pass through the list of items, while also keeping track of which `e_display_id` were seen and what their status was. Then the second pass through the data (iterating through what was seen, but not added), you will immediately know what needs to be added based on your rules.

```js
let arr = [ 
  { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33780, e_display_id: "EA-15-001", status: "Y" },
  { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33744, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "N" },
  { e_type: "P", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" },
  { e_type: "P", e_record_id:   420, e_display_id: "PE-14-911", status: "Y" },
  { e_type: "P", e_record_id:   421, e_display_id: "PE-14-911", status: "N" },
  { e_type: "R", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" },
  { e_type: "R", e_record_id: 33386, e_display_id: "PE-14-016", status: "Y" } 
];

let seen = {};

let filtered = arr.reduce((res, curr) => {
  let type = curr.e_type;
  let status = curr.status;
  let id = curr.e_display_id;
  if (type !== "P") {
    // if type is not "P", we add it unconditionally
    res.push(curr);
  }
  else {
    if (!seen[id]) { seen[id] = {}; }
    if (!seen[id][status]) { seen[id][status] = []; }
    // add to "seen" list for status "N" or "Y" for this e_display_id 
    // so we can decide later whether to keep it or throw it away
    seen[id][status].push(curr);
  }
  return res;
}, [])

// add the e_type = "P" items in to final results based on e_display_id
let finalResults = filtered.concat(Object.values(seen).reduce((res, curr) => {
  // keep Ns, regardless if there are multiples for that e_display_id
  if (curr["N"]) { res.push(...curr["N"]); } 
  // if no Ns, keep Ys as long as no duplicates, 
  // meaning only 1 item in "seen" array for this e_display_id
  else if (curr["Y"] && curr["Y"].length === 1) { res.push(...curr["Y"]); }
  return res;
}, []))

console.log(finalResults);
```